# Vector Projection gives weird results?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics, geometry-nodes, vector

I'm trying to project a vector onto another vector using the Vector Math node's Project mode like this:[image]

However, almost every output is just input B (`1,0,0`). This happens regardless of what A/B are.

[image]

Am I misinterpreting Blender's version of vector projection?
Is there a quick way to get standard vector projection (`1,0,0` onto `1,0,1` is `½,0,½`)?

Comment: FWIW blender's `mathutils.Vector.project` _eg_ `Vector((1, 0, 0)).project((1, 0, 1))`  yields the desired result.

Comment: The GeoNodes implementation is fixed now. Thanks, devs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turns out to be [a fault in the implementation of GeoNode's *Vector Project*](https://developer.blender.org/T88922#1196298), at the time of writing. **Now fixed**. Thanks, @mistajolly.

In the mean time:

[image]

This cluster returns a Vector Projection as defined, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) (Thanks, @batFINGER, for the reference)

Comment: Surely it's as explained in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection  For gnode gnoobs like me, Could you please elaborate on why above as opposed to question setup?

Comment: I've pushed a fix to Blender: https://developer.blender.org/D12029

Comment: @mistajolly Cheers! I got the mail. Didn't expect it would fit into the schedule so soon. Thanks!